# "value must be a number less than infinity" error when the variable is a integer

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm not sure if I should ask this, but the details might help on finding out :p
I have a table like this

[image]

And I'm using `compute` to get the interval where a double variable stands in the `Variavel` column

```
double value = 6;

 double max Convert.ToDouble(DataAccess.Instance.tabela1vert0caso1W.Compute("MIN(Variavel)", "Variavel >= " + value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
 double min = Convert.ToDouble(DataAccess.Instance.tabela1vert0caso1W.Compute("MAX(Variavel)", "Variavel <= " + value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

The problem here is that I get the inifity error on the `double min` line, however it only happens when I'm between 5 and 15, if I choose any other value, i get the program to work properly.

Any hint?

By the way I checked the value of `value` just before the lines, and it's still 6.

Comment: Where is the '=' in the max statement?

Comment: You are using `MIN(Variavel)` to initialize the `max` variable and `MAX(Variavel)` for the `min` variable?

Comment: It can be very challenging to debug code that we can't see, and you're certainly not showing us much of the code. Could you try creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Some definitions/implementation will consider the minimum of an empty collection as being positive infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the actual problem is, however, you could always use [Linq-To-DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is more powerful (supports the whole .NET framework) and also more readable:

```
var variavels =  DataAccess.Instance.tabela1vert0caso1W.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<int>("Variavel"));
double max = variavels.Where(d => d >= value).Max();
double min = variavels.Where(d => d <= value).Min();
```

Comment: I get the same error, and it's always on min, http://puu.sh/goEDx/5c2b538065.png @TimSchmelter  But i can assure you it's exactly that table, and the value is 6. There's no missing data

Comment: @ng80092b: that is _not_ the same error. With the `row.Field<double>("Variavel")` you get an invalidcastexception if the type is different. I guess it is actually an `int`-column. Then use `row.Field<int>` instead. Note that i have changed my answer slightly to make it more compact.

Comment: Actually i'm now getting that error in every singe interval, and not only between 5 and 15

Comment: @ng80092b: as mentioned in my last comment, use the correct type instead of `double`. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also consider the behavior of `Max` and `Min` in case the source (filtered by `Where`) becomes empty. In Linq-To-Objects at least, the `Min` of an empty sequence of non-nullable value types gives an exception, while the `Min` of an empty sequence of types that allow `null` gives `null`. Not sure if it is related to the asker's problem, though.

Comment: Thank you, it helped, how in that case would you create an 2D array of rows with the row with "Variavel" min, and "Variavel" max? I was using this code but its not compatible any more ` DataRow[] rows = DataAccess.Instance.tabela1vert0caso1W.Select("Variavel = " + min.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " OR " + "Variavel = " + max.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
`

Comment: I guess you want: `DataRow[] rows = DataAccess.Instance.tabela1vert0caso1W.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("Variavel")==min || row.Field<int>("Variavel")==max).ToArray()`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: `Linq-To-DataTable` _is_ `Linq-To-Objects`, so your comment applies. He could use `variavels.Where(d => d >= value).DefaultIfEmpty(double.MinValue).Max();`.

Comment: It's working for now, and the source (you mean the variable value?) will never be empty, it comes directly when a textBox is filled and not empty as "". Thank you very much guys, you've been very very helpful

Comment: @ng80092b: no, not the `value` but the query. So if there are no rows left after the filter was applied(f.e. `.Where(r => r.Field<int>("Variavel")<=6)`). Then `Min` or `Max` throw an `InvalidOperationException`. I have handled that above by providing a fallback value `double.MinValue` which is used in case there are no rows.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I think i got that error before, on my case when i choose a value below 5, he will have no row above that to choose, right? I addressed it setting it to 5 if the user tries to get a value below, and it uses the row 5 only without any of this code, it gave some work but it's working perfectly :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its possible for the compute method to return DBNull.Value. It seems unclear when if at all the Max() function will return this, but possibly your select returns 0 rows?

I suggest you add a check for DBNull.Value and set min to value when it occurs